# python import depending on backend data

Tags: python, import, inflate, global

My json store returns serialized data for my class instance, but also the class name of the object to be inflated.

As this logic sits in a `Baseclass` member, and the loaded class names are inherited from `Baseclass`, I believe importing them all in the `Baseclass` file is neither an option (cyclic imports) nor good style ([DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) principle).

Therefore, my code would look something like this:

```
class_str = class_from_db
try:
    exec 'from models import ' + class_str
    globals()[class_str].load_from_data(other_data_from_db)
except:
    raise SomeException()
```

I think it should work, but it doesn't look very pythonic to me. Any issues with that approach? Performance etc.? Is there a better way?

(Maybe it's worthwhile to add that there's not too many sub-classes, so loading all of them in a good place wouldn't be an issue by itself.)

Edit: thanks for the exec tip. That works out, but mainly I'm interested in whether the construct as a whole makes sense and is pythonic, or if there's a better way to solve it given the situation.

Comment: Avoid using `exec` - it's generally considered to be a bad idea. Consider using the `imp` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to import a class based on its string, you can use the `__import__` builtin:

```
>>> __import__('math')
>>> <module 'math' (built-in)>
```

Alternatively, if you want to perform more complicated dynamic import operations, you can refer to the `imp` module.

In either case, I strongly advise against using `exec` or `eval` - there's almost always a better way.